# How do I get the length of a Float64Array as a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

[image: Scope Values of JavaScript Program]

I've attempted to do something like the following:

```
if(tracker.classifiers.Float64Array.length=='33871'){
```

However this doesn't work, so how to get the value of the length of the Float64Array to use it as the value for a if statement?

Comment: Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array and search that page for "length".

Comment: `tracker.classifiers[0].length === 33871` should be sufficient. As a side note, try to avoid using `==`, as sometimes the "loose equality" results in unexpected false positives for edge cases.

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not a great problem statement. Please be more specific. Note that `classifiers` appears to be an array, with a `Float64Array` as its only element, so you'd what `tracker.classifiers[0].length`. The `Float64Array` you're seeing in that screenshot is the type of the 0th element in `classifiers`.

Comment: For future reference, _before posting to Stack Overflow_, try following the relevant steps in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It has tons of helpful advice even if it was intended to target compiled languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classifiers` is an array. It does not have a `Float64Array` property. Rather, that is the *type* of the `classifier` array's first element. Try this instead:

```
if(tracker.classifiers[0].length===33871){
```